# C# - Adding XAML elements to UWP app via x:Bind

Tags: c#, uwp, datatemplate, uwp-xaml, xbind

Context: I'm writing a UWP Twitter client.

One of the useful bits of data Twitter returns via its API are objects for content that can be linked directly in a tweet - #hashtags, @usernames, $symbols, and URLs. This makes it easy to extract these objects from the string containing a tweet's full text, in order to turn them into links.

I understand how the XAML needs to look for this, with `<run>` and `<hyperlink>` tags, and I've figured out how to create that XAML dynamically for each tweet object.

What I can't figure out is how to inject my generated XAML into my app's `DataTemplate`. Because tweet content needs to be displayed on multiple pages in the app, I'm using a `ResourceDictionary` to hold all my XAML styling, including my `DataTemplate`. So, I'm entirely unsure how to connect my generated XAML to my app's UI.

For example, if a tweet looks like this:

"Hey @twitter, you're a time waster! #FridayFeeling"

My generated XAML objects look like this:

```xml
<Run>Hey </Run>
<Hyperlink link="http://twitter.com/twitter/">@twitter</Hyperlink>
<Run>, you're a time waster! </Run>
<Hyperlink link="http://twitter.com/search?hashtag=FridayFeeling">#FridayFeeling</Hyperlink>
```

If there's nothing to link in a tweet's text, then I can just use `Tweet.Text` as-is, so I'm trying to bind this to a `TextBox`. How can I handle inserting this XAML dynamically?

Am I stuck abandoning data binding entirely and looping through my collection to programmatically add all my XAML?

Here's my DataTemplate:

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="TweetTemplate" x:DataType="tweeter:Tweet2">
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource ListItemStyle}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="RetweetedBy" x:Load="{x:Bind IsRetweet}" Height="28">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="4 8 4 0">
                <StackPanel.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageTextBaseMediumBrush}" />
                    </Style>
                </StackPanel.Resources>
                <Border Height="28">
                    <TextBlock Height="24" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" xml:space="preserve"><Run Text="&#xf079;&#160;"/></TextBlock>
                </Border>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path=User.Name}" />
                <TextBlock Text=" retweeted"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path=Tweet.User.Name}" Margin="0 0 8 0"  FontWeight="Bold" />
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path=Tweet.User.ScreenName, Converter={StaticResource GetHandle}}" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageTextBaseMediumBrush}" />
                <TextBlock Text="&#x2981;" Margin="8 0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path=Tweet.CreationDate, Converter={StaticResource FormatDate}}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <TextBlock Text="***this is where I'm having problems***" Padding="5" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="3">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*" MaxWidth="100"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                <Button x:Name="cmdComment" Content="&#xf075;" Style="{StaticResource MetaButtons}" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                <Button x:Name="cmdRetweet" Content="&#xf079;" Style="{StaticResource MetaButtons}" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Column="2">
                <Button x:Name="cmdLike" Content="&#xf004;" Style="{StaticResource MetaButtons}" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Column="3">
                <Button x:Name="cmdMessage" Content="&#xf0e0;" Style="{StaticResource MetaButtons}" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: You can either generate all the contents(runs and hyperlinks) and add them as inlines collection of the textblock via Attachedproperty of converters; or create a custom control so you can use your template and expose some dependencies properties that you'll need to access

Comment: Should I add an array of contents all at once, or add each content item as it's created? I'm not familiar with Attachedproperty - can you expand a little bit on that one?

Comment: It depends on your implementation. If you have all the contents, you will add them at once. The attachedproperty solution is to help you access and control the InlineCollection of the textblock. You can add/remove contents as you want. This will also allow you to use data binding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use attached property, here is an example to start with :

```
public static class Twitter
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InlinesProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Inlines", typeof(ICollection<Inline>), typeof(Twitter), new PropertyMetadata(default(ICollection<Inline>), PropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(d is TextBlock tb)) return;

        tb.Inlines.Clear();

        if (!(e.NewValue is ICollection<Inline> inlines)) return;

        foreach (var inline in inlines)
        {
            tb.Inlines.Add(inline);
        }
    }

    public static void SetInlines(DependencyObject element, ICollection<Inline> value)
    {
        element.SetValue(InlinesProperty, value);
    }

    public static ICollection<Inline> GetInlines(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (ICollection<Inline>) element.GetValue(InlinesProperty);
    }
}
```

And in xaml :

```
        <TextBlock local:Twitter.Inlines ="{x:Bind TwitterData}"></TextBlock>
```

Where TwitterData is a `List<Inline>`

Comment: Ok, I spoke a little too soon - if I try to load the same tweet object again in my XAML (I'm using a `BladeView` control, so clicking a tweet opens it in a new blade), I get this error: `WinRT information: Element is already the child of another element.`

Comment: I can understand that you are reusing some generated contents (inlines) in multiple places. In that case, either use computed properties, or a data structure representing the tweet object and use a converter to generate dynamically the contents. Another option is to use a custom control

Comment: I figured it out - I used `MemberwiseClone()` to make a clone of the selected tweet, and that loads in the second blade without any problems. Thanks again!!

Comment: Good! Just for info : if you use {Binding} instead of x:Bind, with a computed property it will work as well. The computed property must evaluates each time and create the contents. But it only works with {Binding} not with {x:Bind}